# Updating External List after Updating BCS: SharePoint 2013

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I am using SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012, both Enterprise Editions. 
Earlier I had created an External Content Type and created its External List. I have no problem performing various options like Read Item, Read List, Update Item etc.

Later I deleted one column from the SQL Table. Subsequently, I also Edited the deleted column from operations like Read Item, Read List and Update Item etc. and saved the External Content Type.

I am not seeing the updates in the External Lists. I have seen some posts where adding columns in SQL Table and editing operations in ECT automatically updated External List. But it is not happening in my case. I wonder if there is any method instead of deleting and recreating the External List.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any answer on this ?

Comment: No Vikas! Not yet!